# Transactional Email List in Magento Empty by Default

Tags: email, magento

On a clean installation of Magento there are no entries in the list at Admin > System > Transactional Emails.

Every tutorial regarding these speaks as though the list should be populated by default.

My folder app/locale/en_US/emails has html templates in them, but I am guessing that I should not be editing these and rather editing in the admin panel.

Could someone please explain how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, those emails are in the filesystem, and can be manipulated normally from there. If you choose to "promote" them to be in the database, they can be edited via the admin panel, but will not reflect any file changes.

You should also be able to make store-specific adjustments via the DB-driven templates that the filesystem-driven ones do not allow.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Yes thanks, that helps a lot.  How do I go about "promoting" them to the admin panel?

Comment: Sorry, by promote I mean saving a new email template. When you select one, it will pull the contents of the filesystem file and put it into the admin form, which you can then customize and save at will.